# C#: HowTo/which class to create a property that is an iterable/enumerable collection of strings/"Languages"

Tags: c#, types, collections, properties, cultureinfo

Is it possible to define a property in c# that contains a list of all languages as String (e.g English, Russian, Portuguese)?

I currently have this: `public CultureInfo[] AllLanguages { get; set; } = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);`

But I'm trying to get something like `public List<string> AllLanguages {get; set; } = "something"` that holds all languages as Strings, not CultureInfo

Comment: Are you looking for [CultureInfo.EnglishName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.englishname)?

Comment: Perhaps this `public IEnumerable<string> AllLanguages => CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Select(DisplayName)` could work?

Comment: Thank you. This one did the work. Much appreciated!